# Directory issue when connecting VS Code to remote server via ftp-simple

Tags: wordpress, visual-studio-code, ftp

I've set up ftp-simple to connect to my remote server. Files show up fine, however directories appear with [DIR] next to them which, when clicked, disappear with a red line through it, as per image below (template-parts was the directory which I had just clicked on).

As mentioned, files are fine - they load perfectly, but it's the directories which have the issue.

Nothing shows up in the output log when this happens and I can't seem to find anything about this issue elsewhere.

[image]

Comment: Same issue here tried connecting by filezilla in the same time but no results

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The only solution I have found is this.

In vscode, go File->Preferences->Settings.

Then at the search area type this -> ftp-simple.remote-workspace-load-all <- and set it to false.

What this does is, when you first load a directory (the default path that has been set in vsc config), vsc is going to load only the content of this specific directory.

Then, only if you click another directory ([DIR]), it will start to download the content of this directory.

Comment: Hello, for some reason your solution works well but when you want to add a configuration in the settings of ftp-simple, your solution won't work.

Comment: This works for me, but only for a short amount of time.  If I'm working in a directory, then 30 minutes later, I need to explore another directory - I get the same issue as the original post.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this, (ftp-simple.remote-workspace-load-all set to False) but it made no difference, short-term or long-term.

I thought that maybe it was a low resource problem since this FTP extension worked fine with a small set of files, but when I tried this with a full WordPress site this is when many of the subdirectories had this problem. However, I did a full restart of the computer (closing many open programs and Chrome tabs, LOL) and this made no difference. Same subdirectories are "[DIR] FileName"

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).